# how to align texts in equation cases

Tags: equations, align, cases

I need to make an equation case with text following it. That text should be displayed in the middle of the two cases. This is my code:

```
 \begin{eqnarray}\label{eq13}
  a_k =
  \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if $f_i$ has a value $v_k$}, \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  \text{$f_i$ is a non-binary feature, \\$k=1,...,n$}
 \end{eqnarray}
```

It wouldn't work, I want to begin a new line with `$k=1,...,n$`, since it sticks out of the page. I am using ACM format. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{eq13}
  a_k =
  \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if $f_i$ has a value $v_k$}, \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  \text{\quad\parbox{0.4\linewidth}{$f_i$ is a non-binary feature,\\ $k=1,...,n$}}
 \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want begin a new line, simply write

```
%\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq13}
\begin{equation}\label{eq13} %what for eqnarray?
  a_k =
  \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if $f_i$ has a value $v_k$}, \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  %\text{$f_i$ is a non-binary feature, \\$k=1,...,n$}
 %\end{eqnarray}
 \end{equation}
 $f_i$ is a non-binary feature, $k=1$, \ldots, $n$.
```

Comment: I mean I still want the text '$f_i$ is a non-binary feature, $k=1$, \ldots, $n$.' to be part of the equation.

Comment: @daiyue So where should it be? Where should it begin?